# ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, virtual-machine

I'm originally an Ubuntu user, but I have to use a Windows Virtual Machine for some reason.

I was trying to pip-install a package using the CMD, however, I'm getting the following error:

```
from pip._vendor.packaging.utils import canonicalize_name
   ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I used `pip install numpy` and `pip3 install numpy` along with other commands I found while tying to fix the problem.

I checked that pip is available and reinstalled Python to make sure the path is added. I've also made sure that I'm running everything as an administrator. Everything seems to be installed properly, but I keep getting that error.

I've also checked almost all other StackOverflow questions related to this error message.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the exact command you are running that returns the error?

Comment: @CaptainCaveman I mainly used "pip install numpy" and "pip3 install numpy". I've also tried other things while searching, but I don't remember them because they didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that occurred was while using "Python 3.10.11 (64-bit)". Though I reinstalled it the issue continued.

When I downgraded to "Python 3.9.0 (64-bit)", the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problems in venv under python3.9 running on MacOs
on a Nextcloud folder.
When I open up a new project in VS code and select a local folder as workspace it works..!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).